# Wordpress URL trouble

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, external, product

i am working on wordpress site , i would like to send a variable to a php file , and get it back , the php file(new.php) its an external file , i have put it on the directory , when im on my localhost , it works well , but does not when uploded to my domain and i can not access the file , this my code :

```
// Create our XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file           
var url ="http://belcodes.com/new.php";
alert(url);
var fn = tit;
var ln = "";
var vars = "firstname="+fn+"&lastname="+ln;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
var return_data = hr.responseText;
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
}
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";

//here the code of new.php:

<?php
echo'without any post';
if(isset ( $_POST['firstname'] ) ){
echo'with post ';
}
?>

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: What's `var fn = tit;` ?

Comment: Its a defined variable , you can consider it like var fn = 'tit' . but that s not the problem , i can not access the php file new.php